# DecimalFormat Java commas appear as spaces on certain Android devices

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I'm working on an Android calculator app, and while everything works great on me and my partner's devices, others devices we installed the app on are showing weird bugs.

For example: The numbers are formatted using a DecimalFormat object with the parameter "#,###.########".
On our devices, if we type a bunch of 9's for example, it'll show up as
"9,999,999,999" but on some devices, it shows up as "9 9 9 9 9 9 9 999"

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: It's a few thousand lines long haha, that would be a bit hard.

Comment: Add your `DecimalFormat` part logic here.

Comment: Basically, we use BigDecimals to store values and Strings to store formatted versions using the aforementioned parameters

Comment: The devices probably have different localization settings...

Comment: I agree that we need a bit of code and certainly not thousands of lines. What you need to do is [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Even if only verifiable on certain devices it could still very well be of help.

Comment: Breakthrough here: It only doesn't work if the device's language is in FRENCH. In works fine when it's set to English

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out

Comment: I cannot reproduce. With `Locale.FRENCH` I get `9 999 999 999`, not `9 9 9 9 9 9 9 999`.

Comment: That might have been my display algorithm acting up because of the ' ' characters. Now that I set it to Locale.US, everything's working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have the same issue, this was caused by the device's language settings and it can be solved by using a different locale (in this case, Locale.US) in a NumberFormat object